How can I make total size of LVM partition match Used + Available?
I have a weird storage situation that I suspect is because I set up my LVM allocations incorrectly:
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/data-cams  916G  830G   41G  96% /srv/recordings

That is, if the partition is really 916G and I've used only 830G that should leave 86G available, right? Instead of only 41G?
At one point I even saw it showing:
/dev/mapper/data-cams  916G  883G     0 100% /srv/recordings

So maybe the actual capacity is somewhere between and 871G (adding the numbers from first example) and 883G (based on second example).
Why don't those capacity numbers add up between the examples? And is there a way I can get the Size to match the apparent actual capacity instead of being bigger still?
Asking because the DVR software I'm using this partition for is supposed to automatically clean up older recordings when storage for new ones gets low. But if it thinks there's still 916 - 883 = 33 gigabytes remaining when there's really 0 space free, its logic for that might not work as well.

Are you checking df as root or as non-root? Which filesystem are you using and is it ext4?

from a user account both df -h and sudo df -h report the same numbers as above. filesystem is ext4.
